# How to making a repeating list out of tables?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm a little bit trouble with the below task, I'd like to make a repeting list out of a table.
This is the starting point for the list

[image]

And I like to make them into this form:
[image]

How should I make this? Thank you very much for the answers in advance too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g:

```
S = Table[{Subscript[α, i], Subscript[μ, i]}, {i, 5}];
FoldList[Join, S]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = Array[{Subscript[a, #], Subscript[m, #]} &, 5]
Catenate /@ (Take[arr, #] &) /@ Range[5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. For example:

```
Join @@@ Table[{Subscript[α, i], Subscript[μ, i]}, {j,  5}, {i,  j}]
```

> {{Subscript[α, 1], Subscript[μ, 1]},
>   {Subscript[α, 
>         1], Subscript[μ, 1], Subscript[α, 2], Subscript[μ, 
>         2]},
>    {Subscript[α, 1], Subscript[μ, 1], 
>         Subscript[α, 2], Subscript[μ, 2], Subscript[α, 3],
>          Subscript[μ, 3]},
>   {Subscript[α, 1], Subscript[μ, 1],
>          Subscript[α, 2], Subscript[μ, 2], Subscript[α, 
>         3], Subscript[μ, 3], Subscript[α, 4], Subscript[μ, 
>         4]},
>   {Subscript[α, 1], Subscript[μ, 1], 
>         Subscript[α, 2], Subscript[μ, 2], Subscript[α, 3],
>          Subscript[μ, 3], Subscript[α, 4], Subscript[μ, 4], 
>         Subscript[α, 5], Subscript[μ, 5]}}

```
TeXForm @ %
```

> $\scriptsize\left\{\left\{\alpha _1,\mu _1\right\},\left\{\alpha _1,\mu _1,\alpha _2,\mu
>    _2\right\},\left\{\alpha _1,\mu _1,\alpha _2,\mu _2,\alpha _3,\mu
>    _3\right\},\left\{\alpha _1,\mu _1,\alpha _2,\mu _2,\alpha _3,\mu _3,\alpha
>    _4,\mu _4\right\},\left\{\alpha _1,\mu _1,\alpha _2,\mu _2,\alpha _3,\mu
>    _3,\alpha _4,\mu _4,\alpha _5,\mu _5\right\}\right\}$

Alternatively, you can use:

```
Flatten[Take[Table[{Subscript[α, i], Subscript[μ, i]}, {i, 5}], #]] & /@ Range[5]

Table[Flatten[{Subscript[α, #], Subscript[μ, #]} & /@ Range[i]], {i, 5}]
```

> same result